# Mongodb + koja + co-monk returning wrong value?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, koa, co-monk

I am using: [koajs](https://github.com/koajs/koa), [co-monk](https://github.com/tj/co-monk) (mongodb wrapper)

I have the following insert operation:

```
res = yield sessions.insert({
    value: 1
});
console.log(res);
```

It spits out the object in the console:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("560ac28ff13858145218f259"), "value" : 1 }
```

The documentation states that it should return a `WriteResult` as stated [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#writeresults-insert).

What have I misunderstood here? I suppose that `co-monk` has something to do with this?

Comment: Like you mentioned, you're using a wrapper, it could potentially it can return anything it wants.

Comment: @YuriZarubin So it's specific to the module I'm using. Ok post an answer and I'll get in touch with the maker instead.